# how to perform soft delete and update a record in sql

Tags: sql, merge, insert

source data set 1 on day 1:

```
id   name      item_purchased     timestamp      update_timestamp  soft_delete_flag
1    abc         apple case       05/10/2020       null                  N
```

source data set 1 on day 2:

```
id   name   item_purchased     timestamp      update_timestamp  soft_delete_flag
1    abc      watch           05/13/2020         null                  N
```

When the id and name is coming again on day 2., I need to update the previous soft_delete_flag and update_timestamp  and also insert the new record again.

Final table should look like:

`````````````````
id  name   item_purchased     timestamp     update_timestamp     soft_delete_flag
1    abc     apple case       05/10/2020         05/13/2020            Y
1    abc      watch           05/13/2020         null                  N
````````````````
I am using following code but I am only able to insert but not update.
`````````````
MERGE INTO final_table tgt USING source_data src
ON
TGT.id=SRC.id and
tgt.name =src.name
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
TGT.update_timestamp  =  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
TGT.soft_delete_flag = 'Y'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
(
id ,
name  ,
item_purchased,
timestamp,
'Y'
)
VALUES
(
SRC.id,
SRC.name,
SRC.item_purchased,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
'N'
);

Thanks in advance!!
`````````````````